# Open the popup of the particular div

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click on the `class="team-single"` of `id="team-1"` then it should open the `.team-popup` of that particular id.

But it doesn't seem to work.

```
<div class="team-single" id="team-1">
  <div class="team-popup">     
      <span class="close-btn">x close</span>    
  </div>
</div>
<div class="team-single" id=team-2>
  <div class="team-popup">        
      <span class="close-btn">x close</span>   
  </div>
</div>
```

This is what I am using for js

```
jQuery(".team-single").click(function(e) {
    var currentID = this.id || "No ID!";    
    jQuery(" #currentID .team-popup").css({
        display :"block",
    });
  });
```

Comment: What's `#currentID`?

Comment: `$(this).find(".team-popup")`

Comment: Your second id is lacking surrounding quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `find()` with `this` to get current context

```
jQuery(".team-single").click(function(e){ 
     jQuery(this).find(".team-popup").css({ display :"block", 
    });
//Or 
// jQuery(".team-popup",this).css({ display :"block", 
    });
});
```

Why your code did not work :

You stored the ID in a variable, and to access this variable in a selector use:

```
jQuery("#"+currentID+" .team-popup").
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd reduce what you have to just:

```
jQuery(".team-single").click(function(e) {
    jQuery(this).find('div.team-popup').show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Variables aren't substituted inside strings. If you want to use a variable in a string, you have to use concatenation:

```
$("#" + currentID + " .team-popup")
```

But the answers using `$(this).find()` are better solutions. I'm just posting this so you can understand what was wrong with your code.

Comment: thanks lot for explaining . this will be really helpful in future

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
jQuery(".team-single").click(function(e){ 
     $(this).children().css("display", "block");
});
```